# Using UITableView as a photo stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to use a UITableView to create a photo stream (Like in say Instagram). I have code that should be working, but the image is still not being displayed. If i just create a UIImageView that is not part of the table, the image displays, but when I try to add it to the table, it doesn't appear.  The table is appearing, just without the image. Here is the code -

View controller where table is being created

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //    NSInteger sections = self.objects.count;
    //    if (self.paginationEnabled && sections != 0)
    //        sections++;
    //    return sections;
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    PhotoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:self.thumbImage];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[PhotoCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Cell ViewController -

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.thumbImage];

        imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f);
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        self.photoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.photoButton.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f);
        self.photoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.photoButton];

        NSLog(@"Working");
        [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];
    }
    return self; }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state }

#pragma mark - UIView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 20.0f, 0.0f, 280.0f, 280.0f);
    self.photoButton.frame = CGRectMake( 20.0f, 0.0f, 280.0f, 280.0f); }

@end
```

I am sending the image captured in one view to the other using this -

```
PhotoCell *photoCell = [[PhotoCell alloc] init];
    photoCell.thumbImage = self.thumbImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to set the image to an object which is potentially nil.

Your code will not work even if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns a valid cell instance because you are adding the image view in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method which will not be called if the cell is not nil.

I suggest you do something like follows

ViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
PhotoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[PhotoCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

[cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.thumbImage];

return cell;
}
```

Cell Subclass

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Maintain reference to the image view you create.
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f);
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    self.photoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.photoButton.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f);
    self.photoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.photoButton];

    NSLog(@"Working");
    [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];
}
return self; }

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  [self.imageView setImage:image];
}
```

On the same note, I would suggest tht you create prototype cells in the xib/storyboard if you are using one. That would be much easier and elegant way to handle this case.

Comment: The line "[cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.thumbImage]];" results in two warnings, One, saying setImage: was deprecated in IOS 3, the second saying "Incompatible pointer type sending a UIView to a NSString on the thumbImage. @suhas

Comment: Change the method name to setThumbImage instead of setImage.

Comment: I am now getting an error on launch "[PhotoCell setImageView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176a0a10"@suhas

Comment: You need to declare the imageView as a property. Add this in the cell subclass header file @property(nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView

Answer (score 0):

Other than what has been discussed above, you should use an asynchronous image loading for your table view cell or `PhotoCell`. This can be easily done with `UIImageView+AFNetworking`.

I see that you're looking to build an Instagram photo stream. Take a look at [STXDynamicTableView](https://github.com/2359media/STXDynamicTableView) which is a sample code for this. All you need to do is just hook-up the asynchronous image loading into it.